# How can i print array of pixels at a faster rate?

Tags: c, qr-code, pixel

I've got an array of values and they need to be printed on the TFT screen(128*128). In the code below as we can see I've used scale variable (which print pixel to its adjacent cells ) which takes 2 loops and prints pixel by pixel. Is there a faster way of doing this, if so plz let me know...!
As I am not from an electronics background it will be great if things are explained in human language...!

I've tried using bitmap which again prints pixel by pixel!

```
void draw_qr1(uint8_t x, uint8_t y,sFONT* font, uint8_t scale,uint16_t colored)
{
    int *ptr;
    int i, j;
    int p,q;

    ptr=Fontr.table;    //ptr to array 
    for (j = 0; j < font->Height; j++) {    //columns
        for (i = 0; i < font->Width; i++) {     //rows


            if ((*ptr) & (0x80 >> (i % 8))) {
                for(p=0;p<scale;p++)         /*scaling done here*/
                for(q=0;q<scale;q++)
                {
                    drawPixel(x+i*scale+q,y+j*scale+p,BLACK);
                }


            }

            if (i % 8 == 7) {
                ptr++;
            }
        }
        if (font->Width % 8 != 0) {
            ptr++;
        }
    }
}
```

```
void drawPixel(int16_t x, int16_t y, uint16_t color) {
    int point_temp=0;
    // Clip
    if((x < 0) || (y < 0) || (x >= TFTWIDTH) || (y >= TFTHEIGHT)) return;

    x = TFTWIDTH - x;
    y = TFTHEIGHT - y;


    setAddrWindow(x, y, TFTWIDTH-1, TFTHEIGHT-1);


    CS_ACTIVE;
    CD_COMMAND;


    WriteComm(ST7735S_MEMORYWRITE);     //0x2C is MEMORYWRITE command


    WriteData(color >> 8);
    WriteData(color);


    CS_IDLE;
}
```

Comment: I will bet that you bottleneck is not the loop, but the IO operation itself.

Comment: any way to improve that? coz i ve seen lot of displays doing that at great speed.

Comment: Only you know about the device internals and limitations at this point.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify if this is a Raspberry Pi? And what device you have attached? And how?

Comment: Any reason you aren't using a library to update the screen? Do you know if it accepts bulk DMA or blitting?

Comment: Direct writing is slow, it means that your updated buffer needs to be redrawn for every change... Accessing data that's used to draw things directly to screen isn't as simple as it sounds, more often than not, it needs to be synchronized and that's very slow.

Maybe the only thing missing in here is double/triple buffering?

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, the problem is probably that when you end a write sequence with `CS_IDLE` the controller (perhaps, I have not studied the datasheet very carefully) updates the whole display. I would suggest that you do something like this:

1. `CS_ACTIVE`
2. `setAddrWindow(0, 0, TFTWIDTH-1, TFTHEIGHT-1);`
3. `CD_COMMAND`
4. `WriteComm(ST7735S_MEMORYWRITE)`
5. Write **all** display pixels (a whole frame), meaning that you also write the "background" pixels to white or what ever background you have defined. I looked at the ST7735S datasheet and it can automatically increment the x and y addresses. From the datasheet:

> In horizontal addressing mode (V=0), the X-address increments after
>   each byte, after the last X-address (X=XE), X wraps around to XS and Y
>   increments to address the next row. After the every last address (X=XE
>   and Y=YE) the address pointers wrap around to address (X=XS and
>   Y=YS).

6. `CS_IDLE`

This way you also decrease the overhead of addressing the pixels from once every pixel to once for each frame. Give it a try and see if it performs faster.